# select the value which are contain alpha and numeric value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
create table mixedvalues (value varchar(50));

insert into mixedvalues values ('100');
insert into mixedvalues values ('ABC');
insert into mixedvalues values ('ABC100');
insert into mixedvalues values ('200');
insert into mixedvalues values ('EFEA');
insert into mixedvalues values ('EFEA200');
insert into mixedvalues values ('300');
insert into mixedvalues values ('AAFASF300');
insert into mixedvalues values ('400');
insert into mixedvalues values ('AERG400');
insert into mixedvalues values ('500');
insert into mixedvalues values ('AGE500');
```

Here i can get alpha value using following query

> SELECT * FROM `mixedvalues` WHERE `value` REGEXP '^[A-z]+$'

```
 value
 ABC
 EFEA
```

and for numeric value

> SELECT * FROM `mixedvalues` WHERE `value` REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'

```
value
100
200
300
400
500
```

> then how can i get alpha and numeric value?

result should be like

```
value
ABC100
EFEA200
AAFASF300
AERG400
AGE500
```

Comment: Did you try to combine both querys? `SELECT * FROM mixedvalues WHERE value REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND value REGEXP '[A-z]+'`

Comment: If the alphabetic characters are always in front, you just need to change the regex: `SELECT * FROM mixedvalues WHERE value REGEXP '^[A-z]+[0-9]+$'`

Comment: Do you even need regex for this query?  Surely you are just looking for where the mixedvalues is not null?

Comment: @Paul i got expected answer thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is always alpha then numeric the following should work :

SELECT * FROM mixedvalues WHERE value REGEXP '^[A-Z]+-?[0-9]+$'